# How to add a NIC driver to VMware ESXi 5.1 ISO?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I found information about install problems with the release of the NIC drivers of VMware ESXi 5.1 on Power Edge Dell Servers, the install stop with this error message "No network adapters were detected"

http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/b/techcenter/archive/2012/05/08/no-network-adapters-were-detected-error-message-while-installing-esxi-on-dell-poweredge-12th-generation-servers.aspx#Downloading

HP servers have similar issues and they have their own version of EXSi 5.x

How I can add specific drivers to the ESXi ISO?

I found a way to add drivers to non supported NIC cards but this goes into the Hypervisor partition "ESXi install" no into the ESXi ISO

http://ajmatson.net/wordpress/2011/05/vmware-esxi-installation-success-and-addition-of-realtek-8111-onboard-nic-support/

Comment: Have you tried the dell VMware installer?

Comment: Yes, but only I want to know if somebody here have useful tips or hacks to add NIC drivers before trying with the source code and documentation of ESXi it self

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're having a problem with a Dell server, use the Dell ESXi image, as it had the agents and monitoring hooks built-in.

It seems like you're trying to ask how to add drivers to ESXi on non-Dell/non-HP hardware. If that's the case...

**[Use supported hardware.](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php)**

ESXi is bootstrapped by a small [Busybox](http://www.busybox.net) installation. There are only so many device drivers that can be shipped and supported effectively. Many systems that don't seem ESXi-compatible can be made to be compatible by just adding supported storage and network controllers. It's *difficult* to find server-class hardware that isn't supported by ESXi. If you're in a bind, just buy an Intel E1000 network card to complete your installation.

Answer (score 0):

The topic is old but if other people face the same problem:

I recently had the same issue , and could solve it following this blog's method:

https://www.v-front.de/2014/12/how-to-make-your-unsupported-nic-work.html

It basically uses a script to inject the specified nic driver into the specified ESXi iso version. The article is very detailed.

However, I definitely agree with [ewwhite](https://serverfault.com/users/13325/ewwhite);
Using unsupported hardware should *never* be attempted in production environment.

Comment: In general, you should copy the relevant info from that site and quote it here, otherwise this answer is subject to link-rot making it useless.